# Adding a bootstrap4 navbar other places on page besides top

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I would like to have a navbar on a different part of my page instead of the top. On http://www.ellencavallo.com/newsite/ellen the navbar is fixed to the top. I want it below the header picture where the buttongroup currently resides. I cant for the life of me figure out how to place it below the picture and collapse on small screens like the fixed navbar.

Comment: Do you have any code we can look at to try and find the issue?

Comment: the code is in the source of the link provided at the top. I guess the real question would be: is it possible to have a navbar other places on your site instead of fixed to the top?

Comment: Yes, you can put it almost anywhere on the page and it should function the same. They're using Bootstrap for this, which does a lot of the heavy lifting for you. In this case, they have a class on the navbar, 'fixed-top', that fixes the menubar to the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had to take the fixed-top class out of the navbar. Im sorry to ask guys.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are a brand new user to Stack Overflow so I wanted to welcome you to the community.

Congrats on fixing the problem, and don't worry about asking questions.   We all have had what later seem to be silly questions but often these will help other users out.

I think by the time I got to the page it had been fixed.  What I found is that the `<nav></nav>` element can be placed anywhere on the page.  So you could just add it wherever else you want it to appear, and style it as you wish.

In the future, try to include something you've done to figure out the problem, and if there is a way to reproduce the problem (on https://codesandbox.io, or one of the other online javascript/html IDEs) do that as well.  That is the best way to ask HTML related questions.

Best wishes...